# Clear LocalStorage from server-side

Tags: javascript, server-side

Hello I need to clear() my localstorage from the server-side.

The right moment is after inserting some info in the db (info took from the localstorage) and then I need to redirect and clear the localstorage..

I tried with node-localstorage but i can't do it from the controller...

edit:

Im working on Node.js so its Javascript Server Side..

part of the code:

```
var mPA = require('../models/mPedidosAbastecimiento');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var async = require('async');
var LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage,
localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch');

 function postAlta(req, res){
    params = req.body;
    var objDatos = params.objDatos;
    var objDatosParsed = "";
    tipo_de_objDatos = typeof objDatos;

    if (tipo_de_objDatos == "string"){      
        objDatosParsed = JSON.parse(objDatos);          
    }else if (tipo_de_objDatos == "object"){
        stringiii = JSON.stringify(objDatos);
        objDatosParsed = JSON.parse(stringiii); 
    } else {
        console.log("No es ni string ni object, es: "+tipo_de_objDatos);
    }

    var aArt = objDatosParsed.aArticulos;
    var fecha_generacion = params.fecha_generacion;
    var id_sector = params.sector;

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        user: 'xxx',
        password: 'xxx',
        host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
        port: 'xxx',
        database: 'xxx',
        dateStrings : xxx
    });

    connection.connect();

    mPA.getLastNroPa(function (ultimo_nro_pa){

        ultimo_nro_pa = ultimo_nro_pa[0].nro_pa;
        var nro_pa = 1;

        if (ultimo_nro_pa != 0)
            nro_pa = ultimo_nro_pa+1;

        fecha_generacion = changeDate(fecha_generacion);

        async.eachSeries(aArt, function (articulo, callback) {
            var id_articulo = articulo.id_articulo_fk;
            var id_responsable = articulo.id_responsable_fk;
            var id_centro_costo = articulo.id_centrocosto_fk;
            var fecha_necesidad = articulo.fecha_necesidad;
            var urgente = articulo.urgente;
            var cantidad = articulo.cantidad;

            fecha_necesidad = changeDate(fecha_necesidad);          

            var query= "insert into pedidos_abastecimiento(nro_pa, fecha_gen, id_centrocosto_fk, id_responsable_fk, fecha_necesidad, "
                +"id_articulo_fk, cantidad, urgente, id_sector_fk) "+
                "values("+nro_pa+", '"+fecha_generacion+"', "+id_centro_costo+", "+id_responsable+", '"+fecha_necesidad+"', "
                    +id_articulo+", "+cantidad+", "+urgente+", "+id_sector+")"

            connection.query(query, function (err, rows, fields) {
                if (err){
                    throw err;
                    console.log(err)
                }else{
                    console.log("No errors in the query.");
                    console.log(query);
                    callback();
                }
            });

        }, function (err) {
            //HERE IS WHERE I NEE TO CLEAR THE LOCALSTORAGE SO 'paalta' CAN RENDER WITHOUT ANY DATA LISTED
            localStorage.clear();           
            connection.end();
            res.redirect('paalta');
        });     
    });     
}
```

Comment: Which server side language are you using ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It will greatly help if instead of just saying what you did, you share the code you have already tried so we can understand where you are coming from better and can build off that syntax in an explanation

Comment: thank guys, I edited the first post for you

Answer (score 2):

From your server send to client document that contains the following:

```
<script>
  localStorage.clear();
</script>
```

Comment: this is not server side. sorry but this doesnt work for me

Answer (score 1):

Just Clean the Value

```
localStorage.setItem("YourKey","");
```

OR

```
localStorage.setItem("YourKey",null);
```

Comment: or `delete localStorage.YourKey;`; why use a method and why leave it blank?

Comment: or `localStorage.removeItem('YourKey');`

Comment: thank you guys but this doesnt work from the server side